# Regex for string starting with $ followed by integer and contains brackets

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to identify strings with the following criteria:

- Starts with "$"
- followed by integer(1 or 2 digits)
- follower by "="
- contains "(" and ")"

Examples:

```
$6=192 (step port invert mask, int:11000000)
$7=25 (step idle delay, msec)
$8=10.000 (acceleration, mm/sec^2)
$9=0.050 (junction deviation, mm)
$10=0.100 (arc, mm/segment)
$11=25 (n-arc correction, int)
```

The first bit is easy being ^[$] but I can't figure out how combine and test for single and double digits at the same time.

Comment: Where is the position of `(` or `)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
'^\$\d+=.*\(.*\).*'
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't match 1 or 2 digits exactly, but I think the real question here is to match an integer(from the format of example) rather than take it literally.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work. Doing a bit more testing

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex

^\$\d{1,2}=\d+ (.+)

Answer (score 0):

```
\d\d?
\d{1,2}
\d|\d\d
```

Three different ways of matching one or two digits. `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` when UNICODE mode is not set (the default).

Answer (score 0):

`\$\d{1,2}\=\(.*\)`

After `=`, there's nothing? But your examples has digits after it. My example will not match those digits.